# page is not loading when we enable redis tls encryption in moodle

Tags: ssl, redis, moodle

I am facing issue, when enable the redis tls encryption in the page. what might be the issue?

verified all my installation, no issues in the installation.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: NO errors are shown

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding debugging to Moodle - add these 2 lines to `config.php`

```
$CFG->debug = E_ALL | E_STRICT;
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;
```

Also what version of Moodle are you using? If the front end isn't working then check the value for `$release` in `version.php`